# How to set layout on openGl 3d cube?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to inflate layout xml file on 3d cube one side, for next side another layout xml, for next another etc.

I just need on side of 3d cube put gridView and in gridview put some buttons, images, texts.

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can accomplish this:

1. Create a [`Camera`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html) and create transformations for the different sides of your cube.
   [Here](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) is an example of how to use the camera object to achieve a 3d-effect with a view.
   This way don't explicitly use OpenGL, but it should be hardware accelerated on newer versions of Android.
2. Use the [`draw()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29)-method of your layout to draw to a custom `Canvas`, and make an OpenGL texture out of the canvas content:

   ```
   Bitmap layoutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
   Canvas tmpCanvas = new Canvas(layoutBitmap);
   //Load layoutBitmap to a texture and recycle it.
   ```

   Then draw your cube with the new texture.

Unfortunately these solutions won't allow any events on the layout (possibly the first option, but I don't think so) so if you need to be able to click or perform some other action this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to create a bitmap image from layout, maybe help you.

```
private Bitmap imageXML(View view) {

        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

        final Bitmap bp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bp.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bp);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return bp;
    }
```